# When trying to rotate an image: Cannot resolve method mtx.postRotate(int)

Tags: android, image, matrix, bitmap, rotation

I am taking an image from my camera intent but the problem is, it is coming in Landscape mode even when I take the image in portrait mode.

To solve this, I tried to rotate the image but I am getting this error (Mentioned below).

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        File imgFile = new  File(pictureImagePath);
        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            //Rotate image
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                // Notice that width and height are reversed
                Bitmap scaled = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenHeight, screenWidth, ScalingUtilities.ScalingLogic.FIT);
                int w = scaled.getWidth();
                int h = scaled.getHeight();
                // Setting post rotate to 90
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix(); 
                mtx.postRotate(90); //Cannot resolve method 'postRotate(int)'
                // Rotating Bitmap
                bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
            }else{// LANDSCAPE MODE
                //No need to reverse width and height
                Bitmap scaled = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenHeight, screenWidth, ScalingUtilities.ScalingLogic.FIT);
                bm=scaled;
            }

            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

        }
    }
```

**Problem: `mtx.postRotate(90);` is showing: Cannot resolve method 'postRotate(int)'**

Any help?

*Feel free to suggest edits. Any help is appreciated.*

Comment: see `Bitmap.createBitmap` parameter types

Comment: @pskink That is showing error as well, but unable to figure it out. Can you elaborate?

Comment: check `Bitmap.createBitmap` 6th parameter (`Matrix m`) and compare it to your `mtx`

Comment: @pskink It is `Matrix mtx` which it should be. Am I missing on something?

Comment: yes: the full class path: `createBitmap` needs `android.graphics.Matrix` but you are passing ... ?

Comment: @pskink OMG that was silly.  Can you write this as an answer so that I can mark accepted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106828/discussion-between-srujan-barai-and-pskink).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

most likely you are importing `android.opengl.Matrix` when `Bitmap.createBitmap` needs `android.graphics.Matrix`.

that's why you have compilation errors.